# java play midi different from software?

Tags: java, audio, midi

I have wrote a simple code to load and play midi:

```
public class SoundBase {
    Sequencer sequencer;

    public SoundBase() throws Exception{
        sequencer = MidiSystem.getSequencer();
        sequencer.open();

        Sequence sequence = MidiSystem.getSequence(new File("audio/chno0902.mid"));
        sequencer.setSequence(sequence);
//      sequencer.getTransmitter().setReceiver(new MyReceiver());
        sequencer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        new SoundBase();
    }

    @Override 
    protected void finalize() throws Throwable { 
        if (sequencer != null) 
            sequencer.close(); 
        super.finalize(); 
    } 
}
```

However the midi played from this code is really different from what I have heard in preview from the site I have downloaded: [Chopin](http://www.midiworld.com/midis/other/chopin/chno0902.mid)
Also different from the software player I have installed GarageBand (MAC OSX).
Am I doing something wrong or forgotten something?
Thanks

Comment: A midi file does not contain the actual sound of the instruments (waveform) but just the parameters of the individual notes (instrument, pitch, length, ...). That's why it is significantly smaller than a WAV or MP3. The drawback is, it may sound differently on different platforms, depending on how the instruments are implemented.

Comment: I have seen that I can add a soundbank in /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0_66.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/audio I have downloaded it and put there but when I load it i have this error javax.sound.midi.InvalidMidiDataException: cannot get soundbank from stream
 at javax.sound.midi.MidiSystem.getSoundbank(MidiSystem.java:604)
 at SoundBankTest.loadSoundbank(SoundBankTest.java:34)
 at SoundBankTest.main(SoundBankTest.java:72)
java 8 has this bug from 2001?